# Meaning of "have head in the wrong place"

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of *have head in the wrong place*?

> Is a 19 year old too young for a 28 year old?
>
> I don't see it working out but there is no harm in trying. Most 19 year olds have their heads in the wrong place though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means something along the lines of "they aren't thinking straight" or "they aren't thinking about the right things, or the things they should be thinking about". In the example you provided, it appears the statements are referring to a 19 year old having an intimate relationship with someone much older, which many would think is an inappropriate endeavour, or the result of not thinking things through clearly.

Comment: I think it's a little different than that. I don't think it's saying that, because the 19-year-old is dating someone much older, that's an example of them having their head in the wrong place. Instead, I think it's advising the 28-year-old to NOT date the 19-year-old, because the 19-year-old won't have their head in the right place - i.e., they won't have the right level of maturity to be paired up with a 28-year old.

Comment: You may be right, my opinion is that the phrase could be taken either way without further context. Regardless, the question was about the term "head in wrong place" which has nothing to do with whether the relationship advice is being directed at the older or younger person.

Comment: You are absolutely right on both counts: (1) without any further context, either one could be a valid interpretation; (2) regardless of the interpretation, the term itself implies cloudy judgment, or misaligned priorities, or warped thinking. "Head in the wrong place" is like "head in the clouds" or "not thinking clearly" or (as an exclamation): "What are you thinking??"

Comment: I agree except on the 'head in the clouds' part. To me it seems this is more about being lost in thought (which may be perfectly sound and reasonable thoughts), and thus being unaware of what going on around you.

Comment: I think there's some room for interpretation there. Some dictionaries define the [idiom](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/head-in-the-clouds) to mean "flighty"; and define "flighty" as "Characterized by irresponsible or silly behavior."  But I think I've heard that same phrase applied to daydreamers, too, so you've got a point.

Comment: As do you, I have heard it used that way as well, now that you mention it.

Answer (score 4):

Be certain, if you use the phrase, ***always*** to use a possessive to modify *head*. The title of this question makes a rather unfortunate omission.

The idiom being discussed here is

> *to have **one's** head in `<place name>`*

as in

- *He had **his** head somewhere else/in the clouds/in the wrong place,*

and it means what the other answers say it does.

However...

**This** is a completely different idiom, with a completely different meaning

> *to have head (in `<place name>`)*

as in

- *He had head somewhere else/in the clouds/in the wrong place.*

***Executive Summary***: Determiners are not always optional.

Answer (score 3):

Extremes might be "head in the sand" and "head in the clouds" (luftmensch). There's also "head in the game," that is, in the right place:

> Eighteen thousand pounds of milk, as was suggested by Mr. Miller
>   would not need over a twenty-gallon can of starter to ripen that cream
>   properly. Of course I was speaking to the buttermaker that has not got
>   his head in the game. If he had his head in the game he will not only
>   have it on the starter, but will have it on the quality of the cream
>   he is getting. His head will be in the game and he will see that he
>   gets good cream. When you get cream that has gone beyond that stage, I
>   do not think there is a creamery in Iowa large enough hold starter
>   enough to make it good.

*Seventh Annual Year Book* Part VII, Iowa Book of Agriculture, 1907

Comment: "Head in the sand" is more about intentionally ignoring something because it's uncomfortable to acknowledge; the equivalent of putting your fingers in your ears and shouting LALALALA when someone is saying something you don't want to hear. Whereas "Head in the clouds" refers to someone who daydreams or gets caught up in their thoughts to the point of becoming unaware of their surroundings. "Head in the game" seems more closely related to the phrase in the OP...if your head is in the game, you are thinking about the task at hand.

Answer (score 1):

It means that they're not very sensible.

Answer (score 1):

A 28-year-old (usually) has adult responsibilities and as Barrie says, sensibilities.  A 19-year-old has likely never held down a "real" job, lived on their own, or been responsible for bills.  Most of the things a 19-year-old spends their money on are frivolous.